# no element found even if it was present on the webpage

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://dollarupload.com/dl/08c646d60")
browser.find_element_by_id("reg_download").click()
elementlist=browser.find_elements_by_class_name("offer_title")
```

Actually I was trying to get all the class named offer_title and with that I would like to click the link.But as I can see elementlist is empty.Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the elements you want are in an iframe to a different page.

If you get the iframe element and try again from there you might have more luck.

elementlist=browser.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe").find_elements_by_class_name("offer_title")

Comment: I also know about browser.switch_to_frame() feature but I am not able to find the name of the frame

Comment: but this is also not the answer,I thought.Secondly I have also mentioned in the comment that I am not able to find the name of frame

Comment: Ohoh forgive me :) and Thanks Alot .It worked.Please edit your answer so I can upvote it :)

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment, get ready for more downvotes @ScottSchlechtleitner

Comment: My knowledge is limited here, I wrote out what Nimish tried and read the source of the site rather than mucking about with selenium.  Found an iframe and translated the js i would have used into selenium.  It works, theres an iframe there but beyond that i have no idea.  Im glad Nimish had some success, Im not sure if JeffC needs help or not.  Im pretty new to this.